# How to calculate "Squares and Cubes using two methods and while Loop?

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, cube, square

The assignment is:

Use a method to calculate squares and return the answer

Use a method to calculate cubes and return the answer

Set up a while loop to invoke both methods and output the results.

I came up with this, but I dont know how to make the variable change inside the methods as well.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[])
{

    int number = 1;
    int square;
    int cube;

    square = squareNumber(number);
    cube = cubesNumber(number, square);

    System.out.println("\nNumber\tSquare\tCubes");

while(number <= 5)
    {
        System.out.printf("  %d\t  %d\t %d\n", number, square, cube);
        number++;
    }//end Loop

}//end main

private static int squareNumber(int number)
{
    int square;
    square = number * number;
    return square;

}//end squares method

private static int cubesNumber(int number, int square)
{
    int cube;
    cube = square * number;
    return cube;

}//end squares method
} //end class
```

Comment: Your 'cubesNumber' function sh. ould take only one parameter and compute the cube of it, e.g 'number×number×number'.

Answer (score 0):

Call the methods in your loop. Something like

```
while(number <= 5)
{
    square = squareNumber(number);
    cube = cubesNumber(number, square);
    System.out.printf("  %d\t  %d\t %d\n", number, square, cube);
    number++;
} //end Loop
```

otherwise your *computed* `square` and `cube` values will not be recomputed as the loop variable `number` is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to this:

```
public class CubeSquare {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int number = 1;
        int square;
        int cube;
        int squareNumber;
        int cubeNumber;

        System.out.println("\nNumber\tSquare\tCubes");

        while (number <= 10) {

            square = number * number;
            cube = square * number;
            System.out.printf(" %d\t \t%d\t \t%d\n", number, square, cube);
            number++;
        } //end Loop

    }//end main

}
```